# Get MSTeams Teams Usage data via API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have a requirement to show teams usage data in our custom dashboard. We can see "Teams Usage" report with last 7, 30, 90 days in Microsoft Teams Admin center.

[image]

The output we get in CSV from Admin center is as below:
[image]

I checked for Graph API but couldn't find any API to export this report or data.

So, my question is: **Is there any way to export this report or data programmatically? If yes, then guide me towards it.**

Comment: Why don't you contact their help desk?

Answer (score 0):

That info is available from report intended for usage with Power Bi.

[https://reports.office.com/pbi/v1.0/"your](https://reports.office.com/pbi/v1.0/%22your) tenant GUID"

From a Dataverse environment, go into Tables -> Data -> Get Data
You can select Odata, enter in the URL above and import the tables and then carry out whatever magic you need to.

I'm currently working out a way to separate the data based on Department....

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to call the report through the Microsoft Graph directly:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOffice365GroupsActivityDetail(period='D180')](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOffice365GroupsActivityDetail(period=%27D180%27))
When you call the Microsoft Graph directly, make sure to retrieve an Azure AD App token first and supply this as a bearer token in your call. The Azure AD App should have the Report.Read.All permission enabled.

Refer below doc to get Microsoft 365 usage reports:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide

To get Microsoft Teams device usage reports follow this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-device-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0
and to get insights into the Microsoft Teams user activity follow this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hi Prasad,
I checked above links but it not provides any programmatic way to get teams activity usage data. Other links are providing teams user device usage reports and users activity but not teams usage activity.